# Score pattern for bootstrapping using Fmeasure

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using stanford-nlp for pattern scoring (I'm fine with RatioAll). However, When I want to use FMeasure for scoring patterns in the properties file (example.properties), an error appears saying that it's not defined in enum. I can see FMeasure in the original code and respective javadoc as an option for enum. 
How can I use FMeansure for scoring patterns?

Comment: Suggest you paste in the code you're using, format it using SO's tools, and paste the error you get, with some context, also formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, the FMeasure is not implemented. The enum field will be removed from the code in the next release. The reason is that because this is bootstrapped (i.e. no supervised training data), Recall is not really defined. Do you have some way of computing the F-measure in mind?

Comment: Yes I do have some ideas....for scoring patterns we have exactly for different categories like the one we have in "confusion matrix"...We can use F-measure both on category level and pattern level to control drifting...anyway shall we discuss it to find a way for collaboration?